# requirejs exported array reset with [] literal is not exported any more

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I define an array in module A and want to make it public via module B

module A starts like this:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
    exports.flows = [];
```

module B starts like this:

```
define(["require", "exports", 'A/A'], function(require, exports, A) {
    exports.flows = A.flows;
```

When modify the array in module B it will obviously be modified also in module A. Like this:

```
//in module B
exports.flows.push(1);
exports.flows.length //1
A.flows.length //1
```

But when I reset (empty) the array in module A like this:

```
//in module A
exports.flows = [];
```

then the arrays in module A and module B will not be the same any more:

```
//in module B
exports.flows.length //1
A.flows.length //0
```

Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why?

Because doing

```
export.flows = [];
```

...creates a *new* array and assigns it to the `export.flows` property. This has no effect whatsoever on other properties (or variables) that refer to the old array.

Here's a simpler example:

```
var a = [];
var b = a;             // `a` and `b` refer to the *same* array
a.push(1);
console.log(a.length); // 1
console.log(b.length); // 1, both `a` and `b` refer to the *same* array
a = [];                // Now `a` refers to a different array, but `b` still
                       // refers to the previous one
console.log(a.length); // 0, because the new array is empty
console.log(b.length); // 1, because `b` doesn't refer to the same array as `a`
```